# .GET() .prop() not working together jquery

Tags: jquery

So the context is this:

I have some select inputs with cities, when the value changes I need to search for the ID of the parent node 9 levels above of that select input, then split it, and then get the last part of the array given by split.

I know the ID of the target node is in format "someName_SomeNumber" like "node_1234".

I've tried to do that on this function:

```
    $("select[name*=id_city_]").change(function(){
            alert($(this).parents().get(8).prop("id").split("_").last());
            });
```

everything works great if I execute "$(this).parents().get(8)", but when I try to get the ID with prop it says that prop is not a function.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get()` get's the underlying native DOM node, which doesn't have a `prop` method.

You want `eq()`

```
$(this).parents().eq(8).prop("id").split("_").pop()
```

or just use the native `id` property

```
$(this).parents().get(8).id.split("_").pop()
```

Also note that `last()` is a jQuery method, to get the last item in an array the native way, you `pop` it off the end

Comment: `$(this).parents().get(8).attr("id").split("_").pop()` is also another alternative

Comment: @BassemDy - in this case that's an excellent suggestion, for ID's `attr()` is the more appropriate method, not `prop()`, even if the ID is a property as well, and both will work.

Comment: thank you. I knew I was missing something like this.